# Easily check if a number is in a given Range in Dart?

Tags: dart

Is there an operator or function in Dart to easily verify if a number is in a range? Something like Kotlin `in` operator:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html

```
if (i in 1..10) { // equivalent of 1 <= i && i <= 10
    println(i)
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Quite simply, no.  Just use `1 <= i && i <= 10`.

Comment: this is incomplete. should be n >= x && n <= y || n <= x && n >=y

Answer (score 27):

Since the inclusion of extension functions, this answer could be changed slightly if you are okay with doing the checks non-inline.

To my knowledge, there is no built in functions for this, but you could easily create your own extension on `num` to simulate this.

Something like this would simulate a range verification:

```
void main() {
  final i = 2;
  if (i.isBetween(1, 10)) {
    print('Between');
  } else {
    print('Not between');
  }
}

extension Range on num {
  bool isBetween(num from, num to) {
    return from < this && this < to;
  }
}
```

This method in particular is exclusive both from and to, but with minor tweaking and better naming you could easily create extension functions for all of the Kotlin range checks.

Answer (score 12):

I find using clamp more readable. So, to check if i is between 1 and 10, clamp it to the range and compare to itself.

```
if (i.clamp(1,10) == i) {
    print(i);
}
```

[Documentation for clamp](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/num/clamp.html)

Comment: Seems like a bit more work on the computation side, because you really only need the comparison guts of that logic, not the new value part of that logic.  You could just write .between(low, high) as an extension on num if you want the notational convenience.  Edit:  I see another answer already suggests that!

Answer (score 1):

Use [range_type](https://pub.dev/packages/range_type/example) dart package for that.

For example

```dart
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  if (i.contained(5.range(10))) {
    print(i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This ignores the sequence of input

```
extension RangeNum on num {

  bool isBetween(num a, num b) {
   //not  ( both greater || both lesser )
    return !((a > this && b > this) || (a < this &&  b < this));
  }
}
```

make it exclusive

```
  bool isBetweenExclusive(num a, num b) {
    return !((a >= this && b >= this) || (a <= this &&  b <= this));
  }
```